# how can I extract Average in this each ping result and store in file

Tags: python, multithreading

Here I can ping each IP but am not able to extract the Average of the result. Can anyone help, please?

```
import subprocess
import threading
ip_list = []
def ping(host):
    ip_list.append(host+ ' '+ str((subprocess.run('ping '+host +' -n 1').returncode)))

with open(r'input.txt', "r") as input_file:
    hosts = input_file.read()
    hosts_list =hosts.split('\n')
num_threads = 1
number = 0
while number< len(hosts_list):
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=ping, args=(hosts_list[number+i],))
        t.start()
    t.join()
    number = number +1
```

Comment: Can you reformat your code. As it is, it's not runnable

Comment: Reformated the code. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? The command that you're passing to subprocess.run() doesn't look right

Comment: I am using WINDOWS 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found out that using subprocess.run and then getting the returncode you dont get the output but only the return code so usually 0 for a successfull run with no error.
If you want to get the output of the process you have to use subprocess.Popen and then communicate.
Then if you only want the average you have to do some string manipulation with the output to only get the number after "Average".
Here's an exemple:

```
def ping(host):
    output = subprocess.Popen(["ping", host, "-n", "1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    words = str(output).split(sep=" ")
    average = words[words.index("Average")+2].split("ms")[0]
    ip_list.append(host+ ' '+ average)
```